# Help with parametric equation

Tags: curves, parametric

I posted this problem yesterday, but I want to make some changes regarding the questions I asked. Therefore I post it again.

[image: problem]

So here are my questions:

1. What does $C:[0,2\pi]\rightarrow R^2$ mean. Does the interval $[0, 2\pi]$ denote x-values, y-values or t-values?
2. How do I find the unittangentvector? I have done the following:

[image: Solved]

But this is not a vector. This is just another parametric equation for the tangent of the curve, and 
  only
  gives represents points. So how do I find the unittangentvector?
3. I'm also supposed to find the length of the curve. I know that I'm supposed to use this formula

[image: formula]

But I don't know what my $a$ and $b$ values should be do to question number 1.

I really appreciate some help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1. it represents $t$ values and $\gamma(t)=(x(t), y(t))$ is the curve cycloid!

For 2. 
Find $\gamma'(t)=(x'(t), y'(t))=(b(1-\cos t), b\sin t)$ is the tangent vector and unit tangent vector is  $\gamma'(t)/\|\gamma'(t)\|=(b(1-\cos t), b\sin t)/(2b\sin(t/2)).$ 
Note that $\|\gamma'(t)\|=\sqrt{b^2(1-\cos t)^2+b^2\sin^2t}=b\sqrt{1+\cos^t-2\cos t+\sin^2t}=b\sqrt{2(1-\cos t)}=b\sqrt{2.2\sin^2t/2}=2b\sin t/2.$

Calculate the value at $t=\pi.$ You get the tangent vector at $t=\pi.$

Comment: Thank you for responding! I don't understand why you divide by $(2bsin(t/2)$. I thought one where supposed to divived by the length of the tangentvector.

Comment: So doing it like this $[2b,0]/2=[b,0]$ is not correct?

Comment: Ohh, I see my mistaske now. You were right!  But one last question: So for question 3, is $a=0$ and $b=2\pi$ ???

Comment: yes the limits of integration is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. I really appreciate it! :)